# does service worker request, response from server continuously?

Tags: javascript, servlets, push-notification, server-sent-events, service-worker

I'm using server send event to display a notification.I have created a service worker and i used EventSource to connect with the server (in my case i used a servlet. ) once i run the project. everything is working fine.

but the contents inside the event execute countiously. I want to know why?
my other question is

once i close the tab. it stops sending notification. service worker is nunning and server also running. but why it stops?

this is my service worker code.

```
var eventSource = new EventSource("HelloServ");
//MyDiv1 is a custom event
eventSource.addEventListener("MyDiv1",function(event){
    console.log("data from down" , event.data);

    var title = event.data;
    //below notification is displaying continuously. why ?
var notification = new Notification(title, {
icon: 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-icon.png',
body: event.data,
});
notification.onclick = function () {
window.open("http://ageofthecustomer.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/success.jpg");      
        };
    console.log("down");
});
```

this is my servlet code;

```
response.setContentType("text/event-stream");   
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        String upVote = "my up vote";
            writer.write("id:1\n");
            writer.write("event:myid\n");
            writer.write("data: "+ upVote +"\n");
            writer.write("data: "+"new data 2\n\n");
            System.out.println("servlet "+ i);
            writer.flush();
            i++;
writer.close();
```

Comment: This isn't how you're supposed to implement push notifications. The service worker isn't always running, it has a short lifetime.
I suggest you take a look at the demo here: https://serviceworke.rs/push-simple.html

Comment: can't access that url. can you check it again.

Comment: https://serviceworke.rs/push-simple.html
The URL was correct.

Answer (score 4):

Service workers have a limited lifetime, you shouldn't use things like web sockets or server sent events.
Push notifications are implemented in a different way.

In your page, you need to subscribe the user for push notifications. The subscription is an endpoint URL (and a set of keys, if you plan to use payloads). Once the user is subscribed, you need to send the subscription information to your server.

The server will send a push notification to the user via a POST request to the endpoint URL.

The service worker will be awakened when a push notification arrives, its 'push' event handler is going to be executed.

A simple example (for more complex ones, take a look at the [ServiceWorker Cookbook](https://serviceworke.rs/)).

**Page**

```
// Register a Service Worker.
navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
.then(function(registration) {
  // Use the PushManager to get the user's subscription to the push service.
  return registration.pushManager.getSubscription()
  .then(function(subscription) {
    // If a subscription was found, return it.
    if (subscription) {
      return subscription;
    }

    // Otherwise, subscribe the user (userVisibleOnly allows to
    // specify that you don't plan to send notifications that
    // don't have a visible effect for the user).
    return registration.pushManager.subscribe({
      userVisibleOnly: true
    });
  });
}).then(function(subscription) {
  // subscription.endpoint is the endpoint URL that you want to
  // send to the server (e.g. via the Fetch API or via
  // XMLHTTPRequest).
  console.log(subscription.endpoint);

  // Here's an example with the Fetch API:
  fetch('./register', {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      endpoint: subscription.endpoint,
    }),
  });
});
```

**Service Worker**

```
// Register event listener for the 'push' event.
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  // Keep the service worker alive until the notification is created.
  event.waitUntil(
    self.registration.showNotification('Title', {
      body: 'Body',
    })
  );
});
```

**Server**

In the server, simply send a POST request to the endpoint URL.
For example, with curl:

```
curl -X POST [endpointURL]
```

Or, if you're using Node.js, you can use the web-push library (https://github.com/marco-c/web-push):

```
var webPush = require('web-push');
webPush.sendNotification(req.query.endpoint, req.query.ttl);
```

In Java, you could use this class (https://github.com/marco-c/java-web-push) that hides the details of the implementation and the differences between the protocols in the current versions of Firefox and Chrome (differences destined to disappear since Chrome is going to use the Web Push protocol soon).
Here's a "manual" example with a push service that implements the Web Push protocol (currently only works with Firefox):

```
URL url = new URL(endpointURL);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

writer.write("");
writer.flush();
String line;
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println(line);
}
writer.close();
reader.close();
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I'm using java servlets. so, how should i write server side using java instead of using curl or node js ?

Comment: I've added an example to the reply. It isn't strictly related to web push though, it's a simple POST request like any other (you'll find a lot of examples and documentation online about how to send a POST request with Java).

Comment: thanks.
but now i'm having this error in console. i think the sender's id should be mentioned in a manifest.
Error - "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Registration failed - no sender id provided"
so what would be the sender's id ?

Comment: Yes, in Chrome you also need to create a Web App Manifest (https://w3c.github.io/manifest/), see the steps outlined here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API/Using_the_Push_API#Extra_steps_for_Chrome_support

Comment: The Chrome push service (GCM) doesn't yet support the Web Push protocol by default though, so you'll need a little more complex Java snippet.

You need to detect if the endpoint URL is a GCM endpoint URL (basically, if it starts with 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send'). If it does, you'll need to send the POST request to this URL instead of the endpoint URL, set a few request headers and the body of the request.

Comment: There's some source code here, you can take a look at how it works: https://github.com/google/gcm/blob/master/client-libraries/java/rest-client/src/com/google/android/gcm/server/Sender.java

(in particular, look at the post function)

Comment: I've added a reference to this sample class that I've written to make it easier: https://github.com/marco-c/java-web-push

Comment: thank you so much for your response. but i want to know is there a way to implement this with out using GCM. 
I want to use my own server. instead of using GCM. is that possible ?

Comment: No, you have to use the push service that the browser provides.

In Firefox, you can modify the `dom.push.serverURL` configuration value from about:config to use a different server, but you can't change it automatically via JavaScript (in Chrome there might be a similar way to use a custom server, I don't know).

Comment: In chrome you have to modify the sourcecode to avoid GCM.

Comment: can we wake up service worker by any method? By Server Side Events maybe?

Comment: Yes, if your tab is open. If your tab is not open you need to use push notifications.

Comment: I was looking for answer when tab is closed. Thanks anyway