# How to create a service worker with persistence connection

Tags: javascript, java, web-services, webserver, service-worker

I want to create a service worker which have a persistence connection with the server. I can't use GCM or any other third party to do that. i want to implement the server by my own.

When there is an update, Server should push a message and Service Worker should receive it, and display it as a notification. Even there is no relevant tab open it should display the message.
(I tried Eventsource and it is not suit for my requirement.)

And i want a solution in java. 
can anybody give me a solution ?

Comment: This is the third time you've posted this question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35837967/increase-service-worker-life-time; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35150264/why-does-my-service-worker-stop-running; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35030791/does-service-worker-request-response-from-server-countinously

Answer (score 0):

In my mind it is not possible.

The browsers are implemented to trigger `push` event only when they receive a message from GCM for Chrome and the own Mozilla push system for Firefox.

Also you can't use websocket with service-worker.

Maybe you'll be able to do something with the [Periodic synchronization](https://github.com/WICG/BackgroundSync/blob/master/explainer.md) when this feature will be available, but it's not really its purpose.

Comment: How about "webservice client" in java ?
can i use it ?

Comment: does this "Periodic synchronization" work when the service worker is in the idle mode ?

Comment: Yep it will wake up periodically ;)

Comment: Thanks.
the only issue is it won't display notifications immediately. But it'll display it eventually after sometime. is that correct ?